# Consider $f\in L^1$ and let $g(c)=\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)-c|dx$, show $g(c)$ is absolutely continuous and find the formula for $g'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis

The full problem:

[image]

1. Is standard.
2. Follows from reverse triangle inequality of $\|\|_1$ norm
3. I was able to prove $g(c)$ is abolutely continuous as follows:

   $$|g(a_i)-g(b_i)|=|\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)-a_i|-|f(x)-b_i|dx|\leq\int_{0}^{1}|a_i-b_i|=|a_i-b_i| $$
   I am not really sure how to use 1. to prove $g$ is AC, or how to find the formula.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $g$ is AC is immediate from what you have written. Take $\delta =\epsilon$ in the definitio of AC.

To find $g'(c)$ note that the derivative can be taken inside the integral; this is because $|\frac {|f(x)-(c+h)| -|f(x)-c|} h| \leq 1$, so DCT can be applied. Hence $g'(c)=\int_0^{1} \frac  d{dc} |f(x)-c|dx=-m(f(x)>c)+m(f(x)<c)$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

[Proof of AC using a):Since $f(x)-c$ is also integrable we can change $f$ to $f-c$ in a). This gives $$g(c)=\int_0^{\infty} meas(|f(x)-c| >s)ds$$ $$=\int_0^{\infty} meas(f(x)>c+s)ds+\int_0^{\infty} meas(f(x)<c-s)ds.$$ Now make the change of variable $u=c+s$ in the first term and the change of variable $u=c-s$ in the second. You will see that $g$ is the indefinite integral of an integbrable function. Hence $g$ is AC.

[I am using a basic fact from measure theory: if $f$ is integrable then  its indefinite integral is differentiable a.e.. Note also  that AC only gives differentiable a.e., not at every point].

Comment: I am supposed to use a) to show it is AC, I know my proof is correct. I am not sure how to prove it "their way". Regarding the derivative that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @Sorfosh I have edited my answer.

Comment: I ended up with $|\int_{a_i}^{b_i} \mu(f(x)>u)-m(f(x)<u)du|$ and from here we know the functions inside is at most 1 and we are done, correct?

Comment: @Sorfosh Yes, if $g(b)-g(a)=int_a^{b} h(t)dt$ for some integrable function $h$ then $g$ is AC.

Comment: It's not so clear (I think) that the derivative can be taken inside the integral, since the integrand is not *classically* differentiable.

Comment: @PhoemueX I am using a basic fact from measure theory: if $f$ is integrable then  its indefinite integral is differentiable a.e.. Note also  that AC only gives differentiable a.e., not at every point.